# how can I get instance list of specific class in python

Tags: python, class

For example:

```
class A:
    pass


a = A()
b = A()
c = A()
```

if there are class A and A's instance a, b and c.

what I want to do is get a list of [a, b, c] which are instances of A.

Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing that does this automatically. If you want a list of all A's, the `__init__` method should append `self` to the list.